# How to query in .NET EF Core with Linq?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

[image: My EF Diagram]

Hi, I have the relationship table / model like the picture above.

A Teacher can take multiple trainings. A Training/Course can be a FormalTraining or not.
A Teacher may have many students.

Now I want to get list of Students whose teacher has taken a Course where IsFormalTraining == true.

How do I do that in .NET EF Core 2.2 ?

Edited:

models:

```
Teacher
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    ICollection<TeacherStudent> students ; 
}

TeacherStudent{
    int Id;
    int TeacherId;
    int StudentId;
}

Student {
    int Id;
    string Name;
}

TeacherTraining{
    int Id;
    int TeacherId;
    int CourseId;
    DateTime StartDate;
}

Course {
    int Id;
    string Name;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any entity classes or a context set up? Are you working with code-first or database-first? We need more details on your current implementation if we're going to be able to help.

Comment: my table is too big to be displayed in here, so I use this diagram to explain what I need.

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried? Without seeing any code it's hard to solve your specific problem. This has more details on how to structure questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ok.. I have add the code.

Comment: This should *not* be done without all required navigation properties. Please add them first. And then show how you tried to use then so we know the mapping configuration is OK. Otherwise we'll keep running in circles.

Comment: Could you share detailed model with the correct relationship?Please refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a few assumptions based on your classes so you might need to test and tweak, but I imagine it'll look something like this:

```
var students = 
    context.Students.Where(s => 
      context.Teachers.Any(t => 
        t.Students.Any(st => st.StudentId == s.Id) && context.TeacherTraining.Any(tt => 
            tt.TeacherId == t.Id && 
            context.Course.Any(c => tt.CourseId == c.Id && c.IsFormalTraining))));
```

I'm not able to debug this without rigging up a ton of stuff, so you might have to step through it. You could also break this up into more queries, it'll be easy to read and etc, but it probably won't be very efficient (granted, I don't know how efficient this is without running a test).